# Bash: Removing duplicate lines with unique timestamps

Tags: bash, awk

Maybe you guys can help create a custom `awk` function for this application, as I have little experience with bash.

I have `log.txt` with millisecond timestamps and transaction ids (separated by a dash). I want to remove the earliest entry of the same id, if there is one.

```
1396464155-640de058bac28a44b9fde9a6bbd4b5385588934a38ff543c004ecb94d47dc707
1396464330-640de058bac28a44b9fde9a6bbd4b5385588934a38ff543c004ecb94d47dc707
1396464330-a0ae54a927d49e53f66a511e065a3cc99a35ae2eac215f01d99ea9cc59447185
```

To this

```
1396464330-640de058bac28a44b9fde9a6bbd4b5385588934a38ff543c004ecb94d47dc707
1396464330-a0ae54a927d49e53f66a511e065a3cc99a35ae2eac215f01d99ea9cc59447185
```

Here is the script I'm using for logging. The solution should be handled here, possibly by checking if there is a duplicate transaction id before adding a new entry.

```
#!/bin/bash
F=./log.txt
D=`date +%s`
echo ${D}-${1} >> ${F}
```

Comment: Have you explored `grep` yet?

Comment: So, you want _before_ you add an new entry to the file, check the existence of an older ID and if exists, want remove it from a file and add the new one? So, here are some questions: in what rate comes the new transactions? and how big (in lines) is the logfile usually? Asking because if you got an new logentry every second would be impossible every second filter and reorganize the logfile what contains many thousand lines...

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` should do:

```
awk -F- '{a[$2]=$1} END {for (i in a) print a[i] FS i}' file
1396464330-a0ae54a927d49e53f66a511e065a3cc99a35ae2eac215f01d99ea9cc59447185
1396464330-640de058bac28a44b9fde9a6bbd4b5385588934a38ff543c004ecb94d47dc707
```

It saves time stamp into an array `a` using `id` as index. If there are more than one time stamp for `id`, it only uses the latest one.

Test file

```
12-green
12-red
13-green
14-blue
15-orange
15-red
16-orange
```

```
awk -F- '{a[$2]=$1} END {for (i in a) print a[i] FS i}' file
16-orange
15-red
14-blue
13-green
```

To get output sorted

```
awk -F- '{a[$2]=$1} END {for (i in a) print a[i] FS i | "sort -nt-"}' file
13-green
14-blue
15-red
16-orange
```

Answer (score 1):

With `gnu awk`:

```
$ awk -F- '{a[$2]=$0}END{n=asort(a,s);while(++x<=n){print s[x]}}' file
1396464330-640de058bac28a44b9fde9a6bbd4b5385588934a38ff543c004ecb94d47dc707
1396464330-a0ae54a927d49e53f66a511e065a3cc99a35ae2eac215f01d99ea9cc59447185
```

Comment: @Jotne Nothing strange, this expects the second column of the file to be in order as the check is based on that. I can't say for sure what OP's data looks like with the minimal sample provided above.

Comment: On my test file, the color represent ID and should only be printed for largest number of time stamp (I do uses 12,13 etc).  Running your `awk` on my test file with 7 lines, I get all 7 lines printed.  Should be one `green` one `red` etc.  Or I am lost?

Comment: @Jotne `$2!=p` states that second column is different than the last line. In your sample text file, the second columns are in random order. Hence the checks fails and line is printed.

Comment: And then what if some second later an used ID happens again, after one other ID has occurred.  There are noting in OPs telling that IDs are not showing up in random order.  Time log goes off course always forward ;)

Comment: @Jotne True, modified the answer.

Answer (score 1):

With grep:

```
#!/bin/bash
arg="$1"
Log="log.txt"
date=$(date +%s)

tmp=$(mktemp /tmp/log.XXXXXX)
grep -v -- "-$arg" "$Log" > $tmp && mv $tmp "$Log"
[ -f "$tmp" ] && rm -f $tmp

echo "$date-$arg" >> "$Log"
```

running it as:

```
script.sh 640de058bac28a44b9fde9a6bbd4b5385588934a38ff543c004ecb94d47dc707
```

produces - from your input the e.g. the next

```
1396464330-a0ae54a927d49e53f66a511e065a3cc99a35ae2eac215f01d99ea9cc59447185
1396468423-640de058bac28a44b9fde9a6bbd4b5385588934a38ff543c004ecb94d47dc707
```

Comment: This is actually the most helpful comment. Thank you.

Comment: I added `chmod +rwx $Log` so apache could serve the page without a forbidden error.

Answer (score 1):

I add another `awk`.  This uses `tac` to reverse the file, so that we get the ID with highest date.

```
tac file | awk -F- '!a[$2]++' | tac
1396464330-640de058bac28a44b9fde9a6bbd4b5385588934a38ff543c004ecb94d47dc707
1396464330-a0ae54a927d49e53f66a511e065a3cc99a35ae2eac215f01d99ea9cc59447185
```

My test file

```
tac test | awk -F- '!a[$2]++' | tac
13-green
14-blue
15-red
16-orange
```

Answer (score 1):

sort + awk

```
sort -rn file|awk -F "-" '!a[$2]++'
```

#### Explanation

- `sort -rn file` sort the file first

  -n
          Sorts numeric fields by arithmetic value. A numeric field may
          contain leading blanks, an optional minus sign, decimal digits,
          thousands-separator characters, and an optional radix character.
          Numeric sorting of a field containing any nonnumeric character
          gives unpredictable results.

  -r
          Reverses the order of the specified sort.
- `awk -F "-" '!a[$2]++'` remove the duplicate records.